# Currency Calculator SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql

I have two tables, Products and ExchangeRates, I am trying to calculate the Exchange rate. I have created many calculation queries in SQL but for some reason this doesn't seem to output anything, I have tried formatting the query in many different ways, maybe I'm not seeing it right. But so far I have

```
Select ExchangeRates.Rate * sum(Products.Cost) as Total from ExchangeRates
INNER JOIN Products ON Products.ProductsID=ExchangeRates.ID
WHERE ExchangeRates.CurrencyCode = 'EUR' Group BY ExchangeRates.Rate
```

I think its when I put the WHERE clause in, because without it, it calculates(but only the last entered Rate), but I need to specify which rate I want it to calculate.

Exchange Rates Table consists

```
ID (int), CurrencyCode(nchar (3), Rates(decimal, (10,5)
--Data in this table ID 1, CurrecnyCode: EUR, Rates: 1.26
```

Products table

```
ProductID, Itemdescript(nvarchar), CurrecncyCode, Cost(decimal(10,2)
```

Outputs nothing although I have data in both my tables

**UPDATED**

Below answer is correct, but I also noticed that I didnt have 'GBP' in my ExchangeRates table which is why it wouldnt calculate. I wanted to calculate GBP to EUR but I guess it needed GBP in ExchangeRates table

Comment: Please add your table structure, example data, expected output.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? unexpected output? error?

Comment: What means "this doesn't work"?

Comment: No output - means no data. Add data.

Comment: Please also add the tag for your DBMS (PostgreSQL, Oracle, ...)

Comment: There is obviously data in the tables

Comment: Is there any data with `CurrencyCode` 'EUR'? If it calculates without the WHERE clause, it means no `CurrencyCode` with value 'EUR'

Comment: In my ExchangeRates table it has ID 1, CurrencyCode EUR, Rates 1.26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, cleaned up a bit with table aliases:

```
Select er.Rate * sum(p.Cost) as Total
from ExchangeRates er INNER JOIN
     Products p
     ON p.ProductsID = er.ID
WHERE er.CurrencyCode = 'EUR'
Group BY er.Rate;
```

The `on` clause is *highly* suspicious:  it seems very unlikely that the `id` for an exchange rate would be the product id.  Some other field, such as `CurrencyCode` is needed for the `join`:

```
Select er.Rate * sum(p.Cost) as Total
from ExchangeRates er INNER JOIN
     Products p
     ON p.CurrencyCode = er.CurrencyCode
WHERE er.CurrencyCode = 'EUR'
Group BY er.Rate;
```

Comment: YEP! You are Totally Correct! Thank Youu! :) 
I changed the join to CurrencyCode to CurrecnyCode instead of ID and it Worked! :)